# CasperJSでMicrosoft Translatorのアクセストークンを取得できない

Tags: javascript, casperjs

CasperJSでMicrosoft Translatorを使用するため、下記コードでアクセストークンを取得しようとしました。
しかし、本来、アクセストークンを含むjson形式のデータが入っているはずのresponse.dataがnullになります。ヘッダー情報などは正しく返ってきているのですが、なぜなのでしょうか？

ちなみに、dataオブジェクトとheadersオブジェクトの同じ値を使用し、phpで実行すると、正しくアクセストークンを取得できます。

*main.js*

```
"use strict";

var utils = require('utils');
var translator = require('translator');
var casper = require('casper').create({
  exitOnError: true,
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "info",
  pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.63 Safari/537.36',
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    webSecurityEnabled: false,
    ignoreSslErros: false
  },
  stepTimeout: 10000,
  onStepTimeout: function(milliseconds, step) {
    this.echo('stopped step is ' + step);
    this.clear();
  }  
});

casper.start();

casper.then(function() {
  translator.translate();
});

casper.run(function() {
  this.exit();
});
```

*translator.js*

```
"use strict";

exports.translate = function() {

  var tokenUrl = 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13';
  var data = {
    'client_id': 'myClientId',
    'client_secret': 'myClientSecret',
    'scope': 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  };

  casper.thenOpen(tokenUrl,
    {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: {
        'client_id': data.client_id,
        'client_secret': data.client_secret,
        'scope': data.scope,
        'grant_type': data.grant_type
      }
    },
    function(response) {
      utils.dump(response);
    }
  );
};
```

*response内容*

```
{
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pragma",
            "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        {
            "name": "Expires",
            "value": "-1"
        },
        {
            "name": "request-id",
            "value": "1063d5ba-40af-4997-ac27-9b3ba456c6d0"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-Content-Type-Options",
            "value": "nosniff"
        },
        {
            "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
            "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        },
        {
            "name": "Date",
            "value": "Thu, 26 Mar 2015 07:38:52 GMT"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Length",
            "value": "608"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "redirectURL": null,
    "stage": "end",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "time": "2015-01-13T06:39:33.248Z",
    "url": "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13",
    "data": null
}
```

Comment: phpで実行し、レスポンスデータが正しく返ってきたときのヘッダー情報を比較すると、CasperJSで実行したときは、Conncetionヘッダーがありませんでした。phpでは、Conncetionヘッダー値は、「close」となっています。何か関係があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resource.data` は CasperJS 1.1 で追加された独自拡張で、HTTPのレスポンスとは特に関係ないようですね。使用例はAPIリファレンスで `response.data` を検索すると色々出てきました。

- [`eachThen()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#eachthen) では、列挙した各要素
- [`waitForAlert()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforalert) では、 `alert()` に渡されたメッセージ

ソースコードを辿ると、 `response` の大半を占めるレスポンス情報は PhantomJS 由来のようなので、そちらのドキュメントも参考になるかもしれません。（もちろん `data` は記載されていません）

[onResourceReceived | PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html)

自己解決されたように、レスポンスの中身は `this.getPageContent()` で取得し、JSONであれば `JSON.parse()` を使うことになると思います。

> 結果的に、Microsoft Translatorは、トークン情報をhtmlとして返していました。

`getPageContent()` を使うことで、そう思われたのでしょうか。

HTTPからすればどちらもレスポンスの中身に過ぎず、 `getPageContent()` はそれを取得するだけです。得られるデータはHTML、JSON、あるいは他の形式かもしれません。

実際 `getPageContent()` の説明でもTwitterAPIからJSONを取得していますね。

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent

Comment: さん
httpではなく、CasperJSの独自拡張だったんですね。アドバイスありがとうございます。
レスポンスデータの形式については、getHTML()で見ると、htmlのソースが確認でました。

Comment: @sleepingDead ブラウザ上でJSONを表示したとき、「ソースを表示」とすればJSONだけが見えますが、開発者ツール（「要素を検証」とか）ではブラウザがHTMLに整形したものが見えると思います。 （簡単に言えば）前者を取得するのが `getPageContent()` 、後者を取得するのが `getHTML()` です。

Answer (score 1):

```
casper.thenOpen(tokenUrl,
  {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: {
      'client_id': data.client_id,
      'client_secret': data.client_secret,
      'scope': data.scope,
      'grant_type': data.grant_type
    }
  },
  function(response) {
    utils.dump(response);
  }
);
```

上記コード、function引数のところで、

```
function(response) {
  this.getPageContent();
}
```

とすることで、返ってきたデータを確認することができました。

結果的に、Microsoft Translatorは、トークン情報をhtmlとして返していました。
謎は、responseのdata部分には何に使うのかということです。
HTTPについて勉強し直します。お騒がせ致しました。